# Screen distort for corrective lens

Tags: optics, lenses, applied-physics

[image]

Can we apply a screen distort for corrective lens for eye ware instead of using a lens maker? Just test at home with a phone screen and buy at shop.

To reframe the question can we bring to effect a corrective action of wearing glasses with a distort option on screen?

[image]

Comment: Yes; see https://www.technologyreview.com/s/529191/prototype-display-lets-you-say-goodbye-to-reading-glasses/

Comment: @PeterDiehr You are missing the point of a special filter in front of the screen. The filter emulates the corrective lens based on the image. This is impossible without a filter, because image blurring (mathematically convolution) is a lossy operation. Sharpness of a blurred image can be slightly and very approximately increased by deconvolution algorithms, but only in a very limited way. This is a big issue well studied in digital photography.